# How can I delete files that don't match a wildcard?

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

For example, I can delete all `.exe` files using the following wildcard:

```
del *.exe
```

How can I do the opposite, i.e. delete all files that **do not** end in `.exe`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this.

```
FOR /R [directory] %%F IN (*.*) DO IF NOT "%%~xF" == ".[extension]" DEL /F /S "%%F"
```

Or, if you have only one .exe file, it’s even simpler.

```
for %i in (*.*) do if not %i == FILE.EXE del %i
```

Comment: I need to learn the harder ways, too (actually, it isn't so hard), so you got the checkmark. :)

Comment: Thanks. I checked these two solutions in FreeDOS (running in VirtualBox, because my PC runs Linux), and the second one worked (but it’s still for one file). About the first one — it looks like it is only for Windows 2000 and XP. More information is available here: http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct way, here's one scriptless way to do it:

1. Create a subdirectory.
2. Copy all **`*.exe*`** files to the subdirectory.
3. Delete all files (`*.*`) in the current directory.
4. Copy all files in the subdirectory to the current directory.
5. Delete all files in the subdirectory.
6. Remove (**rmdir**) the subdirectory

And here's the code:

```
C:\mydir> mkdir temp
C:\mydir> move *.exe temp
C:\mydir> del *.* /f /q
C:\mydir> move temp\*.exe .
C:\mydir> rmdir temp
```

Comment: if you follow this and do `del *.* /f /s` you will delete the files in temp too (due to the /s parameter)

Comment: @Nyu This is why you shouldn't add code to someone else's post

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will work for you (depends on if you have other read-only files on your  directory) but this should work:

```
attrib +R *.exe
del *.*
attrib -R *.exe
```

Regarding your question, there's no such thing as "excluding" wildcards in DOS default commands

Comment: What if that attribute had already been set?
Now you just mistakenly cleared the attribute.

Comment: right, as I said, depends on the specific case... aruseni's solution up there is more elegant :-)

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the response of the question (was about excluding wildcards): if you do not search for a specific extension, you can use this for-loop:

```
for /F "usebackq" %i IN (`dir /b *^|findstr /i /v <PATTERN>`) DO @echo %i
```

replace "echo" with "del"...