# Command to delete files all files NOT like a wildcard

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-processing, delete-file

I've found this link [How can I delete files that don't match a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972733/how-can-i-delete-files-that-dont-match-a-wildcard) that is pretty similar to what I want to do but all my files have the same extension and I want to do delete all those that don't match a file name with a wildcard. E.g. I want to keep all files that are "DOC*.PDF" but delete all others like Smith.PDF. I've tried modifying the answer given in the link above but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf ^| findstr /biv doc') do @del "%F"
```

The DIR command lists all .pdf files. The result is piped to FINDSTR which discards files that begin with DOC (case insensitive). The result is processed by FOR /F, and each file is deleted individually.

Double the percents if used within a batch script.

Answer (score 2):

Use PowerShell.

```
get-childitem *.pdf -exclude doc*.pdf | remove-item -whatif
```

Naturally, the `-whatif` parameter is for testing purposes. Remove it to actually delete the files.

Comment: The would preferable but I'm on Windows Server 2008 (not R2) without powershell. I should have specified. I need the dos cmd line.